# Prove $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not the product of two identical topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I can only prove this for $\mathbb{R}$: If $\mathbb{R}\cong T\times T$, then $T$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}$ as a closed subspace (e.g. $T\times pt$). Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, so is $T$. So $T$ must be a closed interval, then $T\times T$ is a square, a close quarter of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or $\mathbb{R}^2$, all impossible.

But when it comes to $\mathbb{R}^3$, I don't know how to characterize closed connected subspaces, and cannot use this to produce some useful assertions.

P.S. Can it be generalized, for example to whether $X^n$ can be expressed as a $m$-fold product of identical spaces, assuming some conditions on $X$? Are there **general results** about expressing a space as a product of some identical spaces?

Comment: This seems to be a hard question. See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60375/is-r3-the-square-of-some-topological-space).

Comment: See in particular the references [here](http://blog.plover.com/math/R3-root.html). (This site is mentioned at the MO link given by Zhen Lin, but it’s worth pointing out specifically.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, this question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/60375/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Tyler Lawson below.

> No such space exists.  Even better, let's generalize your proof by converting information about path components into homology groups.
>
> For an open inclusion of spaces $X \setminus \{p\} \subset X$ and a field $k$, we have isomorphisms (the relative Kunneth formula)
>   $$
> H_n(X \times X, X \times X \setminus \{(p,p)\}; k) \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=n} H_p(X,X \setminus \{p\};k) \otimes_k H_q(X, X \setminus \{p\};k).
> $$
>   If the product is $\mathbb{R}^3$, then the left-hand side is $k$ in degree 3 and zero otherwise, so something on the right-hand side must be nontrivial.  However, if $H_p(X, X \setminus \{p\};k)$ were nontrivial in degree $n$, then the left-hand side must be nontrivial in degree $2n$.